# How to insert blob file in oracle database ? ORA-01722: Invalid number

Tags: php, oracle

I have warning while excuting query : ORA-01722: Invalid number

No file is inserted in my database

My functions of Database model :

```php
public function NewDescriptor(int $type = OCI_DTYPE_LOB): OCILob|false
{
  return oci_new_descriptor($this->connection, $type);
}
public function Execute(int $mode = OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS): bool
{
        return oci_execute($this->statement, $mode);
}
```

My function for insert file in File model :

```php
public function insertFile(): bool
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $database->Connect();
        $database->Parse('INSERT INTO table(
                          id_declaration_agression_file, 
                          nom_declaration_agression_file, 
                          taille_mo_declaration_agression_file, 
                          type_declaration_agression_file, 
                          blob_declaration_agression_file, 
                          id_declaration_agression_form
                      ) VALUES
                      (
                          :id,
                          :name,
                          :size,
                          :type,
                          EMPTY_BLOB(), 
                          :id_form
                      ) 
                      RETURNING blob INTO :blob'
        );

        $blob = $database->NewDescriptor(OCI_D_LOB);
        $database->BindByName(':id', $this->getId());
        $database->BindByName(':name', $this->getName());
        $database->BindByName(':size', $this->getSizeMo());
        $database->BindByName(':type', $this->getType());
        $database->BindByName(':id_form', $this->getIdForm());
        $database->BindByName(':blob', $blob, -1, OCI_B_BLOB);

        $database->Execute()) { 
        $database->Commit();
        $blob->free();
        $database->FreeStatement();
        $database->Close();
    }
```

My description of my table :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01722: Invalid number means that you executed SQL statement that tried to convert string to number, but failed. For example, converting ABC to number won't work.

You didn't post table description; I doubt that its name is `table` as you put it because you can't use that name; `table` is reserved for objects of that type:

```
SQL> create table table (id number);
create table table (id number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

(though, if you enclosed its name into double quotes, then it would work, but  that's really bad, bad practice).

---

If it were something else, then your `insert` *might* work:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id        NUMBER,
  4     blob      BLOB,
  5     id_form   NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (id, BLOB, id_form)
  2       VALUES (1, EMPTY_BLOB (), 1);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

So, which values are you really trying to insert?

Comment: When i insert file with 0 kb, the query is executed

Comment: Table description, please.

Comment: I added, sorry my table is in french

Comment: OK, no problem with language. But, column names on screenshot you posted **don't match** columns you use in code you posted so it is difficult to guess what goes where.

Comment: When I put an integer for the size, the insertion is done

Comment: This line caused error : $database->BindByName(':size_file', $this->getSizeMo());

Comment: What is "getSizeMo()"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252491/discussion-between-vh-dev-web-and-littlefoot).